# Stay up-to-date "with" or "on"?

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I want to say

> Stay up-to-date **with/on** technology news

Do I use *with* or *on*?

Comment: They're both equally valid, and both reasonably common. But [*"**keep** up-to-date **with**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keep+up-to-date+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is by far the *most* common form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the NGram for UK usage. If you can't read the "prevalence" figure, it rises above 0.00001% for ***with*** (beating out ***on*** by an order of magnitude, showing Brits have a clear preference)...

[image]

And here's the same chart showing the US usage...

[image]

...where "prevalence" is around 0.000002% (1/5 the BrE value), and there's no real preference.

I won't litter up this answer with any more charts, but [here's one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stay%20up%20to%20date%20on,stay%20up%20to%20date%20with&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,stay%20up%20to%20date%20on;,c0;.t1;,stay%20up%20to%20date%20with;,c0) showing that ***stay*** up to date **on/with** is far less common than the standard ***keep*** everywhere - particularly in BrE. But again, Brits overwhelmingly prefer ***with***, while AmE is more indiscriminate (but for a change, the *trend* suggests AmE will fall into line with BrE on this one! :)

Having said that, of course there's no "right/wrong" issue here. As a "typical" Brit, I probably wouldn't *generate* the ***on*** version myself, but usually I wouldn't notice someone else's use as any more significant than AmE spellings. If you want to play safe (and ride the wave of the future! :) then use ***with***. Half of all Americans will be perfectly happy because that's what they already use. The other half will catch up with the trend towards adopting the BrE standard ***with*** soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

Who is your audience? The important limitation of any idiom is the domain where people have prior understanding of it.

Regional interests in the [search trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22up%20to%20date%20with%22,%20%22up%20to%20date%20on%22&cmpt=q) suggest that while "with" is more common, the usage of the two seems to be highly dependent on geography.

Comment: Hi bluebaby, welcome to ELU. I know you don't have enough reputation points to post comments yet, but this is definitely a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I had to reword my answer above. I believe it is an appropriate answer because it is not asking for clarification, but actually re-wording and explaining the original question.

Comment: @bluebaby: I've just made a meaningless "non-edit" to the answer text to enable me to cancel my downvote (it's just how the site works). As it happens, your Google Trends link does indeed suggest much the same usage split I posted later in my own answer, but to be honest I don't think it makes much of a case because the search volumes are so low. And more to the point, *highly dependent on geography* isn't very informative, in light of what's *really* going on.